# Constructing a function whose domain is $\omega$ using successor operation recursively

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let $x$ be a set. Does there exist a functional relation $f:\omega\to \bf{V}$ which has the following property?
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(0)&=&x\\
f(1)&=&S(x)=x\cup\{x\},\\
f(2)&=&S^2(x)=S(S(x)),\\
&\vdots&
\end{eqnarray*}
($\bf{V}$ is the class of all sets, and $S(-)$ is the successor operation.)

If $x$ is an element of a set which is closed under the successor operation, then maybe one could use the recursion theorem, but what if it is not the case?

Comment: For each set $A$ you can find a set $X$ which contains $A$ and closed under successor operation.

Comment: @tetori How do you know if there exists an inductive set containing $A$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to prove that the function exists. First, prove by induction on $\omega$ that for each $n<\omega$, the function restricted to $n$ exists (call this function $f\upharpoonleft n$). We can map each $n$ to $f\upharpoonleft n$. So, by replacement, there will have to be a set $\{f\upharpoonleft n: n<\omega\}$. Then $\cup\{f\upharpoonleft n: n<\omega\}$ will be the required function.